# How to filter NaT values

Tags: python

I need to filter Nat values and None values in datetime column in Deal_Event table. My code is like this:

```
         currentPictureSql = """\
            SELECT  
                    deal_id as Deal_Id,
                    closing_dt,
                    actual_term_dt,
                    revolve_period_end_dt,
                    auct_call_dt,
                    last_chg_usr,
                    last_chg_dt                 
                from [dbo].[Scdr_Deal_Stg]
            WHERE Run_PK = """ + str(stagePK)

        baseInstance.setSourceConnection('SFGDM.json')
        baseInstance.setCurrentPicture(currentPictureSql)

        previousPictureSql = """\
            SELECT 
                Deal_PK,
                Deal_Event_Type_PK,
                Deal_Event_Dt,
                Modified_User_Desc,
                Modified_Dtm
                from [dbo].[Deal_Event]
             Where Deal_Event_Type_PK IN (SELECT Deal_Event_Type_PK FROM Lkp_Deal_Event_Type where Deal_Event_Type_Field_Nm IN ('actual_term_dt', 'revolve_period_end_dt' , 'auct_call_dt', 'closing_dt'))
        """
        baseInstance.setTargetConnection('SFGDM.json')
        baseInstance.setPreviousPicture(previousPictureSql)

        auditColumns = [
        ("ETL_Modified_By", 'LSDSDE'),
        ("ETL_Modified_Dtm", datetime.now().date()),
        ("Source", 'SCDR'),
        ("Run_PK", runPk)]
        keyColumns = ['Deal_PK', 'Deal_Event_Type_PK','Deal_Event_Dt']
        baseInstance.setColumns(keyColumns, baseInstance.previousPicture)
        dealMasterCols = ['revolve_period_end_dt','auct_call_dt','closing_dt','actual_term_dt']
        lkpColumns = [['Deal_Event_Type_Field_Nm', 'index']]
        for range in range(len(dealMasterCols)):
            lkpColumns.append([dealMasterCols[range],range])

        newDataHeader = ['Deal_PK','Deal_Event_Type_PK', 'Deal_Event_Dt', 'Modified_User_Desc', 'Modified_Dtm']
        entityColumnList = [len(dealMasterCols),len(dealMasterCols)+1]
        lkpColumns = TransformationLib.getLkpSurrogateKeyValue(baseInstance.logger, 'Lkp_Deal_Event_Type', 'dbo', ['Deal_Event_Type_Field_Nm'], 'Deal_Event_Type_PK', 'Deal_Event_Type_PK',
                                                                    ['Deal_Event_Type_Field_Nm'], lkpColumns, baseInstance.targetCnxn, 'inner')
                   
        baseInstance.currentPicture = TransformationLib.getLkpSurrogateKeyValue(baseInstance.logger, 'Deal', 'dbo', ['Deal_Id'], 'Deal_PK', 'Deal_PK',
                                                                           ['Deal_Id'], baseInstance.currentPicture, baseInstance.targetCnxn, 'inner')
        baseInstance.currentPicture = baseInstance.eavTableReversePivot(lkpColumns, 'Deal_PK', newDataHeader, entityColumnList)
        print(baseInstance.currentPicture[0:5])
     
        baseInstance.currentPicture = TransformationLib.selectRows(baseInstance.logger, baseInstance.currentPicture,lambda rec:[entry for entry in rec.Deal_Event_Dt if entry])
        baseInstance.currentPicture = TransformationLib.selectRows(baseInstance.logger, baseInstance.currentPicture,lambda rec: rec.Deal_Event_Dt is not None)
```

It is throwing error that Timestamp Object is not iterable.
How to filter NaT values from Deal_Event_Dt column?is there any similar way to do like I am filtering None values above?

TransformationLib.selectRows looks like this:

> def selectRows(logger, data, select):
> logger.debug(datetime.now())
> logger.debug('selectRows')
>
> ```
> if not isinstance(data, list):
>     logger.exception('data passed in is not list')
>     raise TypeError()
>
> if not UtilityLib.isLambda(logger, select) and not isinstance(select, str):
>     logger.exception('select passed in is not lambda or string')
>     raise TypeError()
>
> try:
>     data = petl.select(data, select)
>     return UtilityLib.getListOfLists(logger, data)
> except:
>     logger.exception('Error while attempting to select rows')
>     raise
> ```

Comment: your first snippet has a very bad indentation i think